# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found при запуске проекта

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Хотел создать редактирование модели с помощью шаблонных хелперов. Все сделал, как автор в этой книге: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.4.php

Но, выдает ошибку о том, что ресурс не найден. В чем проблема ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        BookContext db = new BookContext();
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            Book book = db.Books.Find(id);
            if (book != null)
            {
                return View(book);
            }
            return HttpNotFound(); ;
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Index(Book book)
        {
            db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }



        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```html
**@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model justfortest.Models.Book
<h2> Книга № @Model.Id </h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Название книги")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Author, "Автор")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Author)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, "Цена")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}**
```

**BookContext:**

```
public class BookContext: DbContext
    {
        public BookContext() : base("BookContext")
        { }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    }
```

**Модель Book:**

```
 public class Book
    {
        // ID книги
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // название книги
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // автор книги
        public string Author { get; set; }
        // цена
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

justfortest- название проекта

BookStore - название Бд

Запись в бд есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает как надо. Вы в вашем контроллере возвращаете ошибку 404 если книга не найдена или `id == null`.

```
return HttpNotFound();
```

Значит когда вы вызываете URL /Home/Index параметр `id` равен `null`, естественно контроллер выдает ошибку 404